# Operation timeout error while sending mail through asp.net using gmail smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, sendmail

I am using the code below .. and after submitting the form i m getting the following error :

> Error:System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Consultancy.Registration.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   G:\servetechsolutions\Consultancy\Registration.aspx.cs:line 48Your

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace Consultancy
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

                mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(TextBox4.Text);

                mailMsg.To.Add("ssumishra@gmail.com");

                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                mailMsg.Subject = "Contact Details";

                mailMsg.Body = "akjmsjfh";


                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                smtp.Port = 465;
                //mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");

                smtp.Timeout = 25000;

                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                smtp.Send(mailMsg);

                lblResult.Text = "Thank you. Your contact details and feed back has been submitted.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
            }

        }





        public bool True { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity, is this line: `smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");` hard-coded with your credentials or does it actually read "username@gmail.com", "password"

Comment: Is the email address in the From field the same as the email address passed to the NetworkCredential object? Also have you tried using port 587 instead of port 465? Google also uses that port for SMTP

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the smtp port to 587:

```
smtp.Port = 587;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SmtpClient.TimeOut value is in milli seconds. Default value is 100,000 (100 seconds).
```

So either don't specify value (it'll take default 100 seconds) or give more value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Nadson said, the right port is 587, but to authenticate you also need to allow access from less secure apps in your gmail account. Try it [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

It worked for me, hope it helps..